# If this limit exists and is finite, does the other one have those properties?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)$ exists and is finite, how can I prove (or disprove) that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists and is finite too?

I tried using substitution $u(x) = x^2$ since $\lim_{x\to 0} u(x) = lim_{x\to 0} x^2 = 0$, then I'd have $\lim_{x^2\to 0
}f(x^2)$ which I know exists, but I can't simply say because $\lim_{u\to 0}f(u)$ exists and is finite then it happens for every $x$, I think...

Any help would be very much appreciated for this question

Comment: Consider $f(x)$ which is $1$ for $x>0$ and $-1$ for $x<0$ and undefined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x^2)$is equivalent to the existence of $lim_{x\to 
  0^{+}}f(x)$.

Comment: So, it means that I can't say that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists since I can't be sure about $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)$, right? So the example $f(x) = 1$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$ and undefined at $x=0$ is an example of that as lulu said?

Comment: Yes,that's what I want to say.